# 2 vectors in one plot

Tags: r, plot, graph

I spent a long time trying to figure something out which I thought would be very easy. I have three vectors (or a data frame if you want to make it into one)

```
date <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
group1 <- c(12,13,16,11)
group2 <- c(9,11,10,9)
```

Now I want to create one graph with the date along the x-axis, and two horizontal lines representing the 2 groups. For a bit of context, I did a difference-in-difference regression and want to show the average values for treatment and control group around the event. I'm using panel data and already calculated the mean for both groups at each point in time. Here is a sceenshot I took from my so you can see how I want it to look like.

[image: Graph]

Comment: Does something as simple as `plot(date,group1,type='l');line(date,group2,lty=2)` work?

Comment: Comes up with this: Error in line(date, group2, lty = 2) : unused argument (lty = 2')

Comment: You've got to plot numeric values. Maybe something like  - `matplot(seq_along(date), cbind(group1,group2), lty=1, type="l", xaxt="n");axis(1, at=seq_along(date), labels=date)`

Comment: Oops, `lines(date,group2,lty=2)`, wrong function \*blush\*

Comment: @r2evans - even the first `plot` will error out as the character values in `date` are not finite values for setting x-limits

Comment: Of course ... my quick-off comment suggestion was obviously not tested, just to spark the discussion of *"is a two-step of `plot` and `line` sufficient?"*. Yes, I could correct that but (1) DanY's answer is much better than my half-ass attempt, and (2) it would get more complicated and would just turn into an answer (when DanY's is already good enough). \*sigh\*

Comment: @r2evans - all good, I won't hold you in ill-repute over an S.O. comment. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# plot solid line, set plot size, but omit axes
plot(x=seq(date), y=group1, type="l", lty=1, ylim=c(5,20),
     axes=F, bty="n", xaxs="i", yaxs="i", main="My Title",
     xlab="", ylab="Total Risk-Based Capital Ratio")

# plot dashed line
lines(x=seq(date), y=group2, lty=2)

# add axes
axis(side=1, labels=date, at=seq(date))
axis(side=2, at=seq(5,20,3), las=1)

# add vertical red line
abline(v=2, col="red")

# add legend
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(x=1.5, y=2, legend=c("solid", "dashed"), lty=1:2, box.lty=0, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: omgosh, you forgot the `box`es ... how can you forget the `box`es? and the dashes are way too tight, they need to be looser ... (`</sarcasm>` nice replica of the plot :-)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans -- not sure how to spread out the dashes (`lty=6` maybe), but the box around the legend is no big deal (`box.lty=1`).

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome.  You'll notice when you adapt this for your specific application, that you need to _manually_ place the legend as well as the y-axis labels.  If any of the `args` confuse you, just run the command without the arg and then with the arg to see the difference, which is how I build these plots anyway (start simple, and add one customization at a time).

Comment: Consider using `matplot` instead, which will automatically scale the y axis for both lines (instead of finagling with `ylim` yourself, though of course there are use cases for this as well)